# What are alternatives to this typelist-based class hierarchy generation code?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, typelist

I'm working with a simple object model in which objects can implement interfaces to provide optional functionality. At it's heart, an object has to implement a `getInterface` method which is given a (unique) interface ID. The method then returns a pointer to an interface - or null, in case the object doesn't implement the requested interface. Here's a code sketch to illustrate this:

```
struct Interface { };
struct FooInterface : public Interface { enum { Id = 1 }; virtual void doFoo() = 0; };
struct BarInterface : public Interface { enum { Id = 2 }; virtual void doBar() = 0; };
struct YoyoInterface : public Interface { enum { Id = 3 }; virtual void doYoyo() = 0; };

struct Object {
    virtual Interface *getInterface( int id ) { return 0; }
};
```

To make things easier for clients who work in this framework, I'm using a little template which automatically generates the 'getInterface' implementation so that clients just have to implement the actual functions required by the interfaces. The idea is to derive a concrete type from `Object` as well as all the interfaces and then let `getInterface` just return pointers to `this` (casted to the right type). Here's the template and a demo usage:

```
struct NullType { };
template <class T, class U>
struct TypeList {
    typedef T Head;
    typedef U Tail;
};

template <class Base, class IfaceList>
class ObjectWithIface :
    public ObjectWithIface<Base, typename IfaceList::Tail>,
    public IfaceList::Head
{
public:
    virtual Interface *getInterface( int id ) {
        if ( id == IfaceList::Head::Id ) {
            return static_cast<IfaceList::Head *>( this );
        }
        return ObjectWithIface<Base, IfaceList::Tail>::getInterface( id );
    }
};

template <class Base>
class ObjectWithIface<Base, NullType> : public Base
{
public:
    virtual Interface *getInterface( int id ) {
        return Base::getInterface( id );
    }
};

class MyObjectWithFooAndBar : public ObjectWithIface< Object, TypeList<FooInterface, TypeList<BarInterface, NullType> > >
{
public:
    // We get the getInterface() implementation for free from ObjectWithIface
    virtual void doFoo() { }
    virtual void doBar() { }
};
```

This works quite well, but there are two problems which are ugly:

1. A blocker for me is that this doesn't work with MSVC6 (which has poor support for templates, but unfortunately I need to support it). MSVC6 yields a C1202 error when compiling this.
2. A whole range of classes (a linear hierarchy) is generated by the recursive `ObjectWithIface` template. This is not a problem for me per se, but unfortunately I can't just do a single `switch` statement to map an interface ID to a pointer in `getInterface`. Instead, each step in the hierarchy checks for a single interface and then forwards the request to the base class.

Does anybody have suggestions how to improve this situation? Either by fixing the above two problems with the `ObjectWithIface` template, or by suggesting alternatives which would make the Object/Interface framework easier to use.

Comment: I think your options in terms of template metaprogramming tricks are limited if you need to support VC6.

Comment: @jalf: I'm definately limited, yes - I was still hoping for an improvement within these limits. :-]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like that ?

```
struct Interface
{
    virtual ~Interface() {}
    virtual std::type_info const& type() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class InterfaceImplementer : public virtual Interface 
{
    std::type_info const& type() { return typeid(T); }
};

struct FooInterface : InterfaceImplementer<FooInterface>
{
    virtual void foo();
};

struct BarInterface : InterfaceImplementer<BarInterface>
{
    virtual void bar();
};

struct InterfaceNotFound : std::exception {};

struct Object
{
    void addInterface(Interface *i)
    {
        // Add error handling if interface exists
        interfaces.insert(&i->type(), i);
    }

    template <typename I>
    I* queryInterface()
    {
        typedef std::map<std::type_info const*, Interface*>::iterator Iter;
        Iter i = interfaces.find(&typeid(I));
        if (i == interfaces.end())
            throw InterfaceNotFound();

        else return static_cast<I*>(i->second);
    }

private:
    std::map<std::type_info const*, Interface*> interfaces;
};
```

You may want something more elaborate than `type_info const*` if you want to do this across dynamic libraries boundaries. Something like `std::string` and `type_info::name()` will work fine (albeit a little slow, but this kind of extreme dispatch will likely need something slow). You can also manufacture numeric IDs, but this is maybe harder to maintain.

Storing hashes of type_infos is another option:

```
template <typename T>
struct InterfaceImplementer<T>
{
    std::string const& type(); // This returns a unique hash
    static std::string hash(); // This memoizes a unique hash
};
```

and use `FooInterface::hash()` when you add the interface, and the virtual `Interface::type()` when you query.

Answer (score 3):

`dynamic_cast` exists within the language to solve this exact problem.

Example usage:

```
class Interface { 
    virtual ~Interface() {} 
}; // Must have at least one virtual function
class X : public Interface {};
class Y : public Interface {};

void func(Interface* ptr) {
    if (Y* yptr = dynamic_cast<Y*>(ptr)) {
        // Returns a valid Y* if ptr is a Y, null otherwise
    }
    if (X* xptr = dynamic_cast<X*>(ptr)) {
        // same for X
    }
}
```

`dynamic_cast` will also seamlessly handle things like multiple and virtual inheritance, which you may well struggle with.

Edit:

You could check COM's QueryInterface for this- they use a similar design with a compiler extension. I've never seen COM code implemented, only used the headers, but you could search for it.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` doesn't work across DLL boundaries though, which is a deal breaker for me. That's the whole "raison d'être" for this selfmade RTTI. Furthermore, the interface system in my question allows to return different interfaces at *runtime*. `dynamic_cast` is based on C++ types, which are static.

Comment: @Frerich: Didn't mention that you needed that in OP.